# Effective classes in toric Kähler manifolds

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds, toric-varieties, holomorphic-symplectic

In an article about toric manifolds, I have seen the following notions, which I don't understand. We view a symplectic toric manifold $(M,\omega)$ as a Kähler manifold with Kähler form $\omega$, and first Chern class $c$.

---

It is said that the cohomology class $[\omega]$ and the first Chern class $c$ are *effective*, which means that they are Poincaré dual to some holomorphic hypersurfaces.

**Question 1:** why is that true ?

---

We call a homology class in $H_2(M,\mathbb{Z})$ *effective* if it has non-negative intersection indices with fundamental cycles of all compact holomorphic hypersurfaces in $M$.

**Question 2:** What kind of intersection index are we talking about here?

Would this definition be equivalent to saying that a homology class $A \in H_2(M,\mathbb{Z})$ is effective if for any compact holomorphic hypersurface $B \in H_{n-2}(M, \mathbb{Z})$, the natural pairing $\langle B, A \rangle$ is non-negative ?

---

From now on, we suppose that the cohomology class $[\omega]$ is integral, that is, it is the image of an element in $H_2(M,\mathbb{Z})$.

---

**Question 3:** Is there any relation between the quotient $\underset{A \text{ effective}}{\max} \langle c, A \rangle / \langle [\omega], A \rangle$ and the cup-length of the toric manifold $M$ ?

**Question 4:** In the article, the cohomology class $[\omega]$ is assumed to be *primitive*. What does this mean ?

---

Toric manifolds can actually be constructed via a process called *symplectic reduction*: given the linear action of the torus $(S^1)^n$ on $\mathbb{C}^n$, and a subtorus $\mathbb{T}^k \subset (S^1)^n$, one can choose a regular value $p \in \text{Lie}(\mathbb{T}^k)^* \simeq \mathbb{R}^k$ of the moment map $P$ associated with the $\mathbb{T}^k$ action on $\mathbb{C}^n$, and define a toric manifold a the quotient $M_p := P^{-1}(p) / \mathbb{T}^k$. Given this construction, there is an isomorphism
$$\mathbb{Z}^k \simeq H_2(M, \mathbb{Z}),$$ which identifies the set of effective homology classes with the intersection of the lattice $\mathbb{Z}^k$ with the first orthant in $\mathbb{R}^n \simeq \text{Lie}((S^1)^n)$.

**Question 5:** what is this isomorphism, and why does this identification hold ?

Comment: The first Chern class equals the cycle class of the sum of all irreducible components of the open torus orbit.  So, in projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$, that is the sum of the (cycle classes) of the $n+1$ coordinate hyperplanes.

Comment: Thanks @Jason Starr. I don't understand what your claim is. Does any sum of irreductible components of the torus orbit correspond to holomorphic hypersurface ? How I can we see that ?

Comment: "How I can we see that?"  For a holomorphic action of a torus $T\cong (\mathbb{C}^\times)^r$ on a complex manifold $X$, the "derivative" of the action is an induced holomorphic map of holomorphic vector bundles $u:\mathfrak{t}\otimes_{\mathbb{C}}\mathcal{O}_X \to T_X$, where $\mathfrak{t}$ is the Lie algebra of $T$ and where $T_X$ is the (holomorphic) tangent bundle of $X$.  Assuming that there exists an open, free $T$-orbit, i.e., $X$ is a toric manifold, then the determinant of $u$ is (locally) a holomorphic function whose zero locus is the sum of these irreducible components.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you have a reference for the answers to my questions ? Do you know why we use the term "effective" ?

Comment: I also don't really understand what you mean by tensoring with $\mathcal{O}_X$.

Comment: Grauert's book "Coherent Analytic Sheaves" is an excellent reference about coherent analytic sheaves such as $\mathcal{O}_X$, $T_X$, and $\mathfrak{t}\otimes_{\mathbb{C}}\mathcal{O}_X$.  A cohomology class on a compact Kaehler manifolds is "effective" if it equals the (Poincare dual) of a sum of cycle classes of closed analytic subvarieties of the Kaehler manifold.  For instance, the zero locus of the "holomorphic function" $\text{det}(u)$ is a closed analytic subvariety whose cycle class represents the first Chern class.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you happen to have an idea of what could be the link between cup-length of $M$ and the quotient of question 3, assuming $[\omega]$ is integral and primitive (whatever it means) ?

Comment: Regarding question 4, $[\omega] $ is primitive means that there is no class $a \in H^{2}(M,\mathbb{Z})$ and integer $k>1$ such that $[\omega] = k a$, It is analogous to the notion of primitive vector in $\mathbb{Z}^{n}$. Note that we can always scale a (integral) Kähler form so that it is primitive.